# Confirming if the toilet drain is properly installed

Tags: plumbing, drain

I have a toilet drain done, but when I flush the toilet, the water is not rushing down the bowl, but rather takes time to develop the spin.
I am wondering if this is the right way to do it and use short 90degrees, rather than long turns[image]

Comment: The tee mentioned in the answer appears to have a sweep (or at least directional) component built in.  My concern would be the amount of fall.  That line appears level in the pic... and you know what they say “sh_t runs downhill”

Comment: That's going to fail an inspection. You can't use a sanitary-T for a vertical-to-horizontal horizontal-to-horizontal junctions. You're asking for blockages in both places. You should be using a wye + 1/8 bend for both.

Comment: Tyson, I think it would be hard to tell level from a photo.  Andrew, you need 1/4" per foot for proper flow.  Have you checked the fall?  Tyson is right, if you have too much or too little fall, you'll get blockages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues come to mind here.

First, I think the way your toilet is flushing is not related to the way your waste lines are plumbed.  Unless you have another toilet of the same make and model that flushes differently, I think that's just how yours works.  Even if your venting was nonexistent, your 4" waste line should have plenty of air space to let it work ok.

Second, I do think you have a problem with your waste line.  I'm assuming the close vertical pipe is the drop from the WC?  If so, the next fitting down, the Tee, needs to have a sweep.  I found [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/121999/dwv-fittings-when-to-use-a-sweep-instead-of-an-elbow) elsewhere in stackexchange.